# Need help set my parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, parameters

I have not idea why this damn script is not working please help!!!

I just want to get the info using my date parameters. All I get is columns with no information pulled.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GerberCutter]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@startdate Date,
@enddate Date,
@designid varchar (7)

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.



SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT DISTINCT 
SL.SALESID,
SL.DESIGNID,
DS.NAME as [DESIGN NAME],
CAST(ceiling(SL.MMI_WIDTHDIMENSION/12) as nvarchar(5)) + 'x' +     CAST(ceiling(SL.MMI_LENGTHDIMENSION/12) as nvarchar(5)) AS SIZE,
SL.QTYORDERED as QTY,
DATEADD(ss,CCS.MMI_CONFIRMTIME, CCS.CONFIRMDATE) as ORDERCONFIRMED,
(SELECT TOP 1 DL.Timestamp FROM DESIGNS.DBO.DesignLog DL WHERE DL.DESIGNNBR=SL.DESIGNID AND DL.NOTES like '%CONVERT%PRODUCTION%') AS CUTFILE,
(SELECT TOP 1 DL.Timestamp FROM DESIGNS.DBO.DesignLog DL WHERE DL.DESIGNNBR=SL.DESIGNID     AND DL.DESIGNER='MTR' and DL.ACTION='P' and DL.NOTES like '%INLAID%') AS CARPETCUT,

DATEDIFF(hour, (DATEADD(ss,CCS.MMI_CONFIRMTIME, CCS.CONFIRMDATE)), (SELECT TOP 1 DL.Timestamp FROM DESIGNS.DBO.DesignLog DL WHERE DL.DESIGNNBR=SL.DESIGNID AND DL.DESIGNER='MTR' and DL.ACTION='P' and DL.NOTES like '%INLAID%')) as HOURSTOCOMPLETE,
Case 
          When (SELECT TOP 1 DL.Timestamp FROM DESIGNS.DBO.DesignLog DL WHERE  DL.DESIGNNBR=SL.DESIGNID AND DL.DESIGNER='MTR' and DL.ACTION='P' and DL.NOTES like '%INLAID%')  Between DateAdd(hh, 07, @startdate) And DateAdd(hh, 14, DateAdd(mi, 59, @enddate)) Then 'S1' 

When (SELECT TOP 1 DL.Timestamp FROM DESIGNS.DBO.DesignLog DL WHERE DL.DESIGNNBR=SL.DESIGNID AND DL.DESIGNER='MTR' and DL.ACTION='P' and DL.NOTES like '%INLAID%')  Between DateAdd(hh, 15, @startdate) And DateAdd(hh, 22, DateAdd(mi, 59, @enddate)) Then 'S2' 

When (SELECT TOP 1 DL.Timestamp FROM DESIGNS.DBO.DesignLog DL WHERE DL.DESIGNNBR=SL.DESIGNID AND DL.DESIGNER='MTR' and DL.ACTION='P' and DL.NOTES like '%INLAID%')  Between DateAdd(hh, 23, @startdate) And DateAdd(hh, 30, DateAdd(mi, 59, @enddate)) Then 'S3' 

End As [CARPETCUT SHIFT]

FROM DESIGNS.DBO.DesignLog DL

INNER JOIN AXLIVESALES.DBO.SALESLINE SL
ON SL.DESIGNID=DL.DESIGNNBR AND SL.RECID=DL.AxRecordId

INNER JOIN DESIGNS.DBO.DESIGNS DS
ON DL.DESIGNNBR=DS.NBR

INNER JOIN AXLIVESALES.DBO.CUSTCONFIRMSALESLINK CCS
ON CCS.SALESID=SL.SALESID AND CCS.DATAAREAID=SL.DATAAREAID

INNER JOIN INVENTDIM ID
ON SL.INVENTDIMID=ID.INVENTDIMID AND ID.DATAAREAID='V02'

WHERE 
SL.DESIGNID = @designid and  DL.DESIGNER='MTR' and DL.ACTION='P' and DL.NOTES like          '%INLAID%' and SL.DATAAREAID='MMI'and (SELECT TOP 1 DL.Timestamp FROM DESIGNS.DBO.DesignLog DL WHERE DL.DESIGNNBR=SL.DESIGNID AND DL.DESIGNER='MTR' and DL.ACTION='P' and DL.NOTES like '%INLAID%') = @enddate

ORDER BY CARPETCUT DESC;

END
```

Comment: What is your database structure? Also it refers to DESIGNS database, just for being sure you wanted to make a query over 2 databases or 1 database, if 1 are you creating procedure on DESIGNS DB or another one?

Comment: I want to make a query on 1 database. I am just joining columns from other databases. As far as structure I am not totally sure because I am helping out a friend

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure you have the start date and end date passed to the correct parameters when executing the procedure?  Is there, perhaps, some locale confusion happening, with month numbers being interpreted as days and visa versa?